# How do I map the keyboard media control keys to switch tabs instead?

Tags: mac, keyboard, tabs, keybindings

These days I get all my music needs from streaming websites, so the media keys on my keyboard are basically useless to me:

[image: Media keys]

I want to map them to `cmd+[` and `cmd+]`, which is the shortcut to change tabs across many mac applications (Chrome, SublimeText). Can this be done and if so how do?

Comment: Funny, your using the exact image as this article http://lifehacker.com/5651055/free-your-macs-media-keys-from-itunes-no-manual-hacking-required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV,
    KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_NEXT,
    KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

For some keyboards you might need to replace `__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV` with `__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_PREV`.

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook is called Karabiner now

Answer (score 1):

[BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/documentation-faq/new-bettertouchtool-documentation/) is probably the easiest way to do this (and unlike KeyRemap4MacBook, it lets you control key-remappings on a per-app basis).

Comment: KeyRemap4Macbook does also support application-specific settings. See the "specify application" part in the first link in my answer.